# How to Copy Data from Column Range and Paste to Next Empty Cell in Table Row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to paste data from a Range into the next empty cell in a Table Row on a different sheet.

I can copy and paste into the table but not to next empty cell, the copied data just keeps overriding existing data. I would prefer to keep the table.

Thanks

```
Sub ZulilyData()                                                         
  With Sheets("Orders")
   Sheets("Orders").Select
   .Range("D2", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
   Sheets("Source").Select
   Range("TableSource[Item '#]").Select
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
   SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Orders").Select
   .Range("F2", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
   Sheets("Source").Select
   Range("TableSource[Quantity]").Select
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
   SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
  End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Do both have to start in the same row, or do both operations have to start new rows? I.e. After the copy of D2:D4, the table will have 3 extra rows. Does the column F-copy have the same row targets or create again 3 extra rows? When dealing with Tables this is an important difference.

Comment: Hi Rik Sorry for the late reply. Yes,if i understand correctly. There will be data from several different sheets that i need to populate the table column. so, the table will expand down to accommodate all the data creating as many rows needed. Hope this clarifies. Thanks